# Why does this MySQL statement throw a syntax error?

Tags: mysql

**SQL statement:**

```
INSERT INTO order (`ORDER_ID`,`SALE_CODE`,`CREATED_AT`,`UPDATED_AT`) VALUES ('2646253286','HPHS20','2009-07-11 12:07:40','2009-07-11 12:07:40')
```

**Error:**

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (`ORDER_ID`,`SALE_CODE`,`CREATED_AT`,`UPDATED_AT`) VALUES ('2646253286','H' at line 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a table called `order` which is a reserved word in SQL. I'm not exactly sure how to get around it in MySQL, but in SQL Server it would be something like

```
insert into [order] ...
```

Comment: Actually, in SQL Server, you'd use [tablename] to fix this. The databasename prefix won't work, because even if you do use it you'd then need the schema (2005 onwards) or owner (2000 backwards) in between.

Answer (score 5):

Fix backticks (`) around order to fix this.